# Watching Events - Best Practice?

Tags: web3js, javascript

I'm using Truffle (Webpack Box) and watching events on the front end. I'm having to design around ensuring I do not initiate watching for events more than once. Is there a best practice on how to do this? Is there a quick way to tell if an event is already being watched?

Answer (score 1):

When you start watching the events with

```
filter = myInstance.EVENT(filter, additionalFilter, callback)
```

you can store the returned `filter`. If you have the `filter` and your callback didn't run into an error, you can assume that you're watching, otherwise the watching has stopped.

If you want to explicitly stop watching the events, call `filter.stopWatching()`.

Comment: Thanks, that approach makes sense. Do you know of any issues with testrpc duplicating events? I'm using this approach, and I can tell that I'm not duplicating the event watch, but I'm seeing multiple events of the same pop up.

Comment: Can you observe the same behaviour with duplicates when you run your code with geth/parity? I am working with ganache-cli 6.1.0 (successor to testrpc) right now and I didn't observe any issues watching events.